# Multiselect control in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

I would like to use Multiselect control of jQuery. See [here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)

Did anyone use this? Will the controls preserve its states after a post back. My page is using excessive use of update pane. Will it work fine with UpdatePanel ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is now nonsense, given that the original link (OP) isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it safely there should be no problem after a postback..